# How to use fonts in the node.js backend?

Tags: javascript, node.js, fonts

**Background:**

I am building a node.js-based Web app that needs to make use of various fonts. But it only needs to do so in the backend since the results will be delivered as an image. Consequently, the client/browser does *not* need access to the fonts at all in my case.

**Question:**

I will try to formulate the question as little subjective as possible:
**What are the typical options to provide a node.js backend with a large collection of fonts?**

The options I came up with so far are:

1. Does one install these hundreds or thousands of fonts in the operating system of the (in my case: Ubuntu) server?
2. Does one somehow serve the fonts from a cloud storage such as S3 or (online) database such as a Mongo DB server?
3. Does one use a local file system to store the fonts and retrieve them?
4. ...other options

I am currently leaning towards Option 1 because this is the way a layman like me does it on a local machine.

Without starting a discussion here, where could I find resources discussing the (dis-)advantages of the different options?

**EDIT:**

Thank you for all the responses.
Thanks to these, I noticed that I need to clarify something. I need the fonts to be used in SVG processing libraries such as p5.js, paper.js, raphael.js. So I need to make the fonts available to these libraries that are run on node.js.

Comment: How are you planning on rendering the images in Node.js?

Comment: I use paper.js and similar libraries (which works already!). These then use the fonts in SVG format and later also export to *.png. This works already as well.

Comment: Will this work https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/paperjs/mdjv-LrUS1Y ?

Comment: I think the answer depends entirely on what your rendering system expects.  If it's expecting installed fonts in your system, then you have to do that.  If you can pass it cloud storage references or local paths, then you could use that too.  But, it just depends entirely on what your renderer expects.

Comment: "nodejs" has no need for fonts, so your question isn't specific enough. If you are asking this in the context of "how do I create an image of text in nodejs?" the answer *there* informs your choice of where to place fonts, and how to index them. All the solutions I know can load fonts from file and do not need them installed in any way: they're just resources, so stick them in a fonts folder, build an index.js or simple db that provides you with some sane mapping from font file location to short string, and there's a perfectly workable solution for thousands of fonts.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans: I am sorry. You can see that I am a total noob. I  clarified my initial post. I need the fonts for SVG processing libraries that run on top of node.js. Examples are paper.js, raphael, or p5.js. I need to make the fonts available to these libraries.

Comment: Those are all client-side libraries. Node.js runs as your server, so it sounds very much like you still don't quite know what you're asking, and are asking an [XY question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Start simpler, like googling for "nodejs text with font to svg" or something. There are a *lot* of pure javascript, node-loadable libraries that let you turn "text style using font X" into SVG outlines.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans: You could have been right. But in this case, I actually DO know what I am asking. These libraries can be run on the server-side and they work very well on my node server already. Especially, paper.js can be easily run on the server-side; the others are a bit more tricky.
Coincidentally, I just also independently discovered fontkit that you recommended below. It actually seems like I can load the fonts this way. Thank you!

Comment: twg recommended it, not you. I confused your user names.

Comment: fontkit's one, opentypejs another, and I'd still argue that you only sort of did: paper.js et al. will happily run server side but are a general purpose graphics libraries (I use many myself, too). However, when writing utility scripts (which this would be), always try to find the right hammer for your nail, paper.js or raphael is using an entire workshop instead of a good hammer =) Another option, if you have it, is to *not use node*. That sounds odd, but I make Node generate a .tex file, call `xelatex`, and then call `pdf2svg`, for instance. That can give you far more typesetting control.

Answer (score 1):

The key to your question is

> hundreds or thousands of fonts

Until I took that in there is no real difference between your methods. But if that number is correct (kind of mind-boggling though) I would:

1. ***not*** install them in the OS. What happens if you move servers without an image? Or move OS?
2. Local File system would be a sane way of doing it, *though you would need to keep track manually of all the file names and paths for your code*.
3. **MongoDB - store file names+paths in the collection..and store the actual fonts in your system**. 
   In advent of  moving servers you would have to pick up the directory where all the actual files are stored and the DB where you hold the file name+paths.
4. If you want you can place it all in a MongoDB but then that file would also be huge, I assume - that is up to you.

Choice #3 is probably what I would do in such a case.

Comment: Thank you, @twg!

The number is correct ;)
My Web app is trying to use fonts in a creative way - so I need to work with hundreds or even thousands of them.

Do you know if JavaScript libraries (on top of node.js) such as paper.js, p5.js etc. can work with fonts if the font is provided as a file path only - rather than installed in the operating system?

Comment: @pascal not sure about that - but take a look here: [fontkit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fontkit)

Answer (score -1):

If you have a decent enough server setup (e.g. a VPS or some other VM solution where you control what's installed) then another option you might want to consider is to do this job "out of node". For instance, in one of my projects where I need to build 175+ as-perfect-as-can-be maths statements, I offload that work to XeLaTeX instead:

1. I run a node script that takes the input text and builds a small but complete .tex file
2. I then tell node to call "xelatex theFileIJustMade.tex" which yields a pdf
3. I then tell node to call "pdfcrop" on that pdf, to remove the margins
4. I then tell node to call "pdf2svg", which is a free and amazingly effective utility
5. Then as a final step mostly to conserve space and bandwidth, I use "svgo" which is a nodejs based svg optimizer that can run either as normal script code, or as CLI utility.

(some more details on that [here](http://pomax.github.io/1489108158510/localization-is-hard#so-what-about-that-latex-is-maths-notation-universal-), with concrete code [here](https://github.com/Pomax/BezierInfo-2/blob/master/tools/tex-to-svg.js))

Of course, depending on how responsive a system you need, you can do entirely without steps 3 and 5. There is a limit to how fast we can run, but as a server-side task there should never be the expectation of real-time responsiveness.

This is a good example of remembering that your server runs inside a larger operating system that might also offer tools that can do the job. While you're using Node, and the obvious choice is a Node solution, Node is also a general purpose programming language and can call anything else through `spawn` and `exec`, much like python, php, java, C#, etc. As such, it's sometimes worth thinking about whether there might be another tool that is even better suited for your needs, especially when you're thinking about doing a highly specialized job like typesetting a string to SVG.

In this case, LaTeX was specifically created to typeset text from the command line, and XeLaTeX was created to do that with full Unicode awareness and clean, easy access to fonts both from file and from the system, with full OpenType feature control, so would certainly qualify as just as worthwhile a candidate as any node-specific solution might be.

As for the tools used: XeLaTeX and pdfcrop come with TeX Live (installed using whatever package manager your OS uses, or through MiKTeX on Windows, but I suspect your server doesn't run on windows) pdf2svg is freely [available on github](https://github.com/dawbarton/pdf2svg), and svgo [is available from npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/svgo))